# Incrementing and displaying a field if not empty

Tags: php

I've got this code to work, but being really new to PHP, I don't know if this is proper. This is my first time using PHP to increment.

1. I have 10 fields for YouTube videos (using Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress - I don't have the repeater fields and won't be getting them)
2. The video/html elements only show if the corresponding video field is not empty

Are the variables correctly placed?

Are there better ways to do this?

```
    <?php
         $vidnum = 'video_';
         for($n=0; $n<=9; $n++) {
         $next = $vidnum.($n +1 );
         $video = get_field('' . $next . '');
             if (!empty($video))
                    echo '<div class="video ' . $next . '">' . $video . '</div>';
                }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>      $vidnum = 'video_';
> ```

Presumably `$vidnum` is short for `$video_number`, but this isn't a video number.  It's the prefix before the video number.

```
     $video_number_prefix = 'video_';
```

You can go ahead and call it what it is.

> ```
>      for($n=0; $n<=9; $n++) {
>      $next = $vidnum.($n +1 );
> ```

You say that you have ten fields but you write `9`.  There are two ways to write it with `10`.

```
     for ( $n = 0; $n < 10; $n++ ) {
```

But the second works better with your `$next` variable, which I'm going to rename to `$video_identifier`.

```
     for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
         $video_identifier = 'video_' . $i;
```

You don't need to save the value of the string literal.  You only use it once, so you can just use it.

Starting with `1` instead of `0` means that you don't have to add `1` to the value before using it.

I switched from `$n` to `$i`, as `$i` is a more common loop iteration variable.

> ```
>      $video = get_field('' . $next . '');
> ```

This seems more complicated than it needs to be.

```
         $video = get_field($video_identifier);
```

Adding the empty strings doesn't seem to accomplish anything.

> ```
>          if (!empty($video))
>              echo '<div class="video ' . $next . '">' . $video . '</div>';
> ```

The single statement version of an `if` is harder to read and maintain.

```
         if ( ! empty($video) ) {
             echo '<div class="video ' . $video_identifier . '">' . $video . '</div>' . "\n";
         }
```

I also added a line break at the end.  Functionally this won't matter, but it makes the HTML easier to read.

The whole thing:

```
<?php
     for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
         $video_identifier = 'video_' . $i;
         $video = get_field($video_identifier);
         if ( ! empty($video) ) {
             echo '<div class="video ' . $video_identifier . '">' . $video . '</div>' . "\n";
         }
     }
?>
```

This also fixes your indentation issues.

Note that I'm not commenting on your use of [`get_field`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/).  Looking at the documentation, it seems that `get_field` depends heavily on the configuration.  Without the configuration, that is off-topic for review.

Comment: whoa, great answer. Works just perfectly. `get_field` is just part of Advanced Custom Fields - so no worries about that.